# how to compare two faces in Android

Tags: android, image, image-processing, bitmap, image-comparison

I was developing an app which compare the face which is stored in SD card and the image shown in camera preview with the help of Surface view. I wrote code to detect the face and created a bitmap which will contain the face only. I need to compare this bitmap and the image in SDcard.  How can I compare these two images in Android ?

Suppose I have these two images .

[image] [image] 
I want to compare these two images by face detection . I have cropped the faces from these two images and now want to compare these two faces . How can I compare these two faces in Android ? Any advice is of great help .

I want to build like this : http://www.pictriev.com/fc.php

Answer (score 1):

I am not so sure about face recognition in Android, but there are somethings that you want in Python **OpenCV** and **Scikit Learn**

For Opencv:
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html

For Scikit Learn
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/face_recognition.html

Comment: I have done face recognition . Now I want to compare two faces . So your answer is inappropriate .